# TX_ER in GMII interfaces

Tags: ethernet

I'm working on an FPGA MAC module and I'm kind of confused with TX_ER signal. A '1' in TX_ER means there's a whatever error in the current packet being sent by MAC. To my understanding, a MAC frame consists of protocol specific header and FCS where I don't expect errors occur, and playload from upper layer which should be transparent to MAC. Then where does this error come from? If MAC is aware of this error, why does it send the frame?

Comment: Some types of hubs/repeaters intentionally create errors but I don't remember whether those are still allowed in Gigabit Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the MAC does not have enough FIFO to hold the entire packet. Therefore, it must start transmitting to the PHY before it has the entire packet. If an error condition, such as FIFO underflow, occurs, it may have already started transmitting. By asserting TX_ER, it causes the PHY to generate an unambiguously invalid frame, guaranteeing that no receiver will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If some sort of error occurs while the MAC is sending the frame (say, a transmit buffer underrun) then it has to cut off the frame and indicate explicitly that it is an invalid frame. This is done by bringing tx_er high while transmitting the frame. This signal is transferred via the PHY layer encoding and results in an assertion of the rx_er signal at the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

At least, two common cases--more known than others--are:

- error propagation, and
- carrier extension.

IEEE Std. 802.3, Clause 35, Table 35-1 "Permissible encodings of TXD<7:0>, TX_EN, and TX_ER" briefs the usage of TX_EN in full.

[image]

(Some years ago the IEEE Get program was more open/useful: anyone could download a current IEEE 802.3 free, without registration and/or other borders... Today the registration is mandatory... What should we expect from tomorrow?...)

You wrote that you're working on a MAC design, what is the (normative) ground of your design if not the mentioned standard?